# Imported data are missing in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I had copyed the data folder under wamp/bin/mysql/mysql(v)/data befor formate my computer, then after installing new os and then wamp I replace the data folder.
Now when I opening phpmyadmin the list of databases are showing but under the data base the tables are not shownig.
When I am using the myadminer it shows the lisst of table but not the tables data.

when I am using sqlbuddy one warning is showing in the place of listing tables. warning is like

```
Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in E:\wamp\apps\sqlbuddy1.3.3\dboverview.php on line 215
```

Comment: This probably won't help you case now, but you really should use SQL dumps to backup your database rather than relying on the physical database files, unless you really are experienced with working with the MySQL binary files.

Comment: No I have not use the dump I just copied the data folder and repalce in the new. may be the two version are not equel of mysql.

Answer (score 1):

you should have taken a proper backups - using mysqldump. if you used innodb storage engin and it was configured to keep log files or tablespace files somewhere else - i'm afraid you've lost your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, you have lost your data. In the future create backups frequently and create MySQL dump whenever you want to migrate your database.